# What am I doing wrong with wait() , fork() and times() system call?

Tags: c, kernel, fork, system-calls

I want to make a program that forks **6 times** : the **first child** that forks will fork the other **5 children** (grandchildren) and set them in an endless loop,moreover I want to set a countdown of 5 seconds at the same time the first child is doing the fork. When the countdown ends  I send a signal to the first child to terminate the 5 grandchildren and **print how much usertime and systemtime**  (the first child took). 
I thought on doing something like this:
[image]

the signal that I would send to the first child after the countdown ends would be SIGUSR1, after it received the signal prints the usertime and systemtime via the times() system call   and then it terminates the whole process group with killpg(getpgrp(), SIGTERM);

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/times.h>

void print_time(int signum){
    struct tms t;
    perror("about to print time");
    if ((times(&t)) == -1)
    {
        perror("error times");
        exit(1);
    }

    else
    {
    printf("usertime: %f , systemtime:%f, usertime+systemtime: %f \n",  (double)t.tms_utime, (double)t.tms_stime, (double)t.tms_stime + (double)t.tms_utime);
    killpg(getpgrp(), SIGTERM); //finish the program by killing the whole group id
    }
}


int main()
{

    pid_t ppid = fork();
    if (ppid == 0)
    { //first child
        size_t count = 5;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)  //fork 5 children(or 5 grandchildren) from  the first child and set them in an endless loop
        {

            pid_t pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0)
            {

                while (1)
                {
                }
            }

            else if (pid < 0)
            {
                perror("error forking from child ");
            }
        }
        if (signal(SIGUSR1, print_time) == SIG_ERR)   //set signal to the first child  so it print the time gathered by wait()
        {
            perror("cannot create signal");
            exit(1);
        }
        wait(NULL); //wait for the 5 children and gather time
    }

    else if (ppid > 0)
    { //parent
        if (signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)   //ignore signal so it doesnt affect the parent
        {
            perror("cannot create signal parent");
            exit(1);
        }
        sleep(5);
        perror("going good");
        kill(ppid, SIGUSR1); //send signal to the process group but the parent and grandchildren doesnt get affected  

    }
    else
    {
        perror("error");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I only get the following output:

```
pc@pc-host:~/Git/so/p1$ about to print time: Success
usertime: 0.000000 , systemtime:0.000000, usertime+systemtime: 0.000000
```

**why are all zeros?**
according to this man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html

> The tms_utime field contains the CPU time spent executing instruc‐
>          tions of the calling process.  The tms_stime field contains the CPU
>          time spent executing inside the kernel while performing tasks on
>          behalf of the calling process.

Comment: (a) You don't put the first child into its own process group (`setpgrp()`?).  (b) You send the signal to a single process; to signal a process group, you have send the signal to the negative number whose absolute value is the process group of the first child.  Also, `wait(NULL)` waits for one process to die.  You need a loop to wait for multiple processes to die.

Comment: there are MANY C library functions that should never be called from a signal handler.  For instance `printf()`

Comment: regarding: `perror("cannot create signal");` the actual problem is `signal failed` not that the code failed to create a signal

Comment: the 5 grand children are in 'forever' loops. the one child that has a signal hander will not cause the grand children to exit

Comment: this statement: `kill(ppid, SIGUSR1);` will only send a signal to the parent (which has no signal handler, so it will perform the default action (die) Since the other processes are in the execution chain of the parent, they should also die.  However, the first child does have a signal handler so it will live to perform the signal handler.   (cont)

Comment: (cont) here is what the function `times()` does "Times for terminated children (and their descendants) are added  in  at
       the moment wait(2) or waitpid(2) returns their process ID.  In particular, times of grandchildren that the children  did  not  wait  for  are never seen."  so no tick count values will be collected

Comment: "there are MANY C library functions that should never be called from a signal handler. For instance printf()" Which one do you recommend? "the 5 grand children are in 'forever' loops. the one child that has a signal hander will not cause the grand children to exit" But at the end in print_time() I send a signal to the whole group id so they all exit

Comment: "this statement: kill(ppid, SIGUSR1)..." : but kill(ppid, SIGUSR1);  means that it will just send a signal to one single process in that case the first child?

Comment: "(cont) here is what the function times() does "Times for terminated children (and their descendants) are added in at the moment wait(2) or waitpi....": so necessarily children must terminate in order to get its time?

Comment: I fixed by keeping an array of the grandchildren's pid and terminating the 5 grandchildren afterwards with a signal and put wait in loop thanks